# When to use target="_self"

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

When does the `_self` [frame target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-frame-target) becomes useful or worth using it?

Isn't it (*always?*) the default behavior?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The default can be changed by using the `<base>` tag in the `<head>`:

```
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/" target="_blank"/>
```

In this case, you can use `target="_self"` on a link to override the `target` set by `base`.

Comment: Is this the whole purpose of the target?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other situation where it would be useful; forcing the default would only be of use if you've changed the default, and the only way I know to do that is using the `base` tag.

Answer (score 21):

`_self` target value could also be useful in conjunction with AngularJS's HTML5 location mode when you do need to force full page reload for links with the same base as your single page app.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> Links that contain target element Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b"
>   target="_self">link</a>`
>
> ...

Answer (score 4):

```
<base target="_self"/>
```

Was very handy for me when I had a page I wanted to load into Firefox's sidebar. I wanted any links clicked to stay in the sidebar instead of opening the links in the main window.  Adding the above to the `<head>` fixed me right up and all the page's links stay within the sidebar.