# Clicking an anchor inside an iFrame behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code in jsBin:
http://jsbin.com/iRoROvu/1/edit

It basically has an anchor inside an iframe. If you click the link you will see nothing happens in Chrome but in Firefox it just goes blank.

Here's the same code in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LbNwd/

JavaScript:

```
 var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||     previewFrame.contentWindow.document;     
    preview.open();
    preview.write("Hello World!<br/><a href='#'>Click me!</a>");
    preview.close();
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="preview"></iframe>
```

In this case, if you use Firefox, it creates another iframe inside the existing iframe...and keeps on doing it...like 'Inception'. But the same code works fine in Chrome.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox form targetting an iframe is opening new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab) - in Firefox you have to make sure that your `<a>` tags have explicit "target" attributes.

Comment: perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771047/when-to-use-target-self

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the target. FF seems to be treating `href="#"` as opening the parent URL, which creates another iframe.

Comment: So how do I solve the issue? The suggested link above does not help. Can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should use `href='javascript:void(0);'` instead `href='#'`

OR

You can use `<a href='#' target="preview">Click me!</a>` instead.

I think adding `target="preview"` also should solve your problem.

Just try it once & let us know wether its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

actually, this might be dumb, but I don't like the hash tag, that's why I use `javascript://` whenever possible, but for your case I am sure if you replace your `href` value with either that or `href='javasctipt:void(0)'` it will solve the case, the problem is, i think, that the browser is treating the hash tag as a new url to browse to, and that's why I don't use it, I hope it works for you

Comment: I understand. However, the content inside the iframe is not in my control and the users can basically have any content they want (HTML/CSS/JS). Is there any other solution?

Comment: if the href is not a hash you will not face any problem of that kind, give it a try, change the href='google.com' and see

Answer (score 0):

Why? It's funny, but the "inception" behaviour has to do with what "top of the page" means to Firefox within an iFrame.  If you use `#top` you get the [same results](http://jsfiddle.net/LbNwd/14/show/).

Ideally you should use href='javascript:void(0)' as mentioned in Labib's answer, but since you mentioned it's out of your control then it seems you need a hack.

The really ugly way would be to search the output being printed for `href="#"` and replace it.

But in this kind of situation I think it's better to detect when things have gone bad and do something about it at that point, like this:

```
if (frameElement && frameElement.id === 'preview') {       
    // Think of something clever here, like
    parent.location = parent.location;
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ze3CR/show