# Javascript - Doesn't want Refresh parent page after closing Iframe Modal box

Tags: javascript, iframe

The basics: I have a webpage where a user can click on the iframe to view the picture of car,as soon as  i click on the iframe the parent page get refresh but the URL doesn't change..nevertheless it seems only chrome browser is affected..have check same scenario in other browser but its working fine

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: i just want to is it the browser based issue or a features of chrome browser

Comment: monners i cant bcos i m tester ..i can provide you the uRL and step how to generate the issue

Comment: 1.open the URL in the chrome http://www.gaadi.com/used_car_result.php#city=290

Comment: 2.Click on the image icon ..iframe modal window open..then click on the close link and see the main parent page gets refresh but URL remain as it is..

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code to say what you have done with the iframe.But here is a similar question and see if you are experiencing the same problem with the code.
[Clicking an anchor inside an iFrame behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388664/clicking-an-anchor-inside-an-iframe-behaves-differently-in-firefox-and-chrome)